# How do you expand a matrix to a power?

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have an nxn matrix A, where t is a natural number >0.

Is A^t=A^(t-1)A

or A^t=AA^(t-1)

I would think that the operation of splitting them up into these two should work. However, A and A^(t-1) are different matrices, so Im really not sure which way to arrange this.

there are two possibilities in my mind.

1. Do you:

Is there a natural order to multiplying a matrix that Im not aware of? Are all matrices added to the right/left if not otherwise specified?

1.Or do you:

Or can i choose freely which way to expand it, and just need to be consistent and if i choose to expand further.

i.e
A^t=AA^(t-1) then if i should expand further, I would need AAA^(t-2).

Comment: The first two expressions are identical so it doeasn't make any difference

Comment: Any two polynomials in the same matrix commute.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is associative. You may group the terms in a product however you'd like and you'll get the same answer.